# Understanding SQL Cusros syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

I am looking at an example for `CURSOR` on the following link:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/05/sql-server-simple-example-of-cursor-sample-cursor-part-2/

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO

DECLARE @ProductID INT
DECLARE @getProductID CURSOR

SET @getProductID = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ProductID
    FROM Production.Product

OPEN @getProductID
FETCH NEXT FROM @getProductID INTO @ProductID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @ProductID
    FETCH NEXT FROM @getProductID INTO @ProductID
END

CLOSE @getProductID
DEALLOCATE @getProductID

GO
```

It is a very simple example however I fail to understand following things:

- Why is there a `FETCH` twice in the definition?
- We see it happening when it opens the cursor and then inside the while loop there is same exact `FETCH` happening.
- Is there anything we can do to make the code little bit more cleaner and less redundant?

Comment: Do you want only cursor to do this or any other method. Try to **avoid** cursor's as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first fetch is to populate your variables before you start your loop.

The second fetch is to populate those variables for the next iteration of the loop. The @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 part of the loop will drop you out if you have run out of things for your variables.

Unfortunately that is as clear as I think you can make it for cursors.